# MongoDB converting an array to dictionary

Tags: mongodb

I insert:

```
{
...

"loc":[-124.9973,49.68829] 

...
}
```

and it is stored as:

```
  "loc": {
           "0": -124.9973,
           "1":   49.68829
          }
```

This occurs from mongo command line or via PHP or through RockMongo forms.

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: yes, it works as expected

Comment: I would not expect mongodb itself to do this.  I would first look at the RockMongo forms to see how they map an Input field into a Mongo document.  It looks like you are missing some keys or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I do an insert from the mongo shell I DO NOT get that behavior

```
dmReplSet:PRIMARY> db.aug29.insert( { "loc" : [ -124.9973, 49.68829 ] } );
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
dmReplSet:PRIMARY> db.aug29.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54010c47de66cda372635186"), "loc" : [ -124.9973, 49.68829 ] }
dmReplSet:PRIMARY> db.aug29.find().pretty()
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("54010c47de66cda372635186"),
  "loc" : [
    -124.9973,
    49.68829
  ]
}
dmReplSet:PRIMARY>
```

How exactly are you doing your insert?  Is it through some OR mapping?

On the other hand, if you are trying to do geospacial stuff in MongoDB you probably should read up on it  and be aware it has been evolving and is MongoDB version specific ( http://blog.mongolab.com/2014/08/a-primer-on-geospatial-data-and-mongodb/ and http://myadventuresincoding.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/mongodb-geospatial-queries/ ).

Comment: Interesting. You are right. It is storing it correctly. It was RockMongo not displaying the query results correctly. Thanks.